# Check for `"[]"` in XUnit?

Tags: c#, xunit

I am writing tests for an API. When the API cant find items one requested, it returns a `"[]"`. How do I check for `"[]"` in Xunit. I have tried,

```
obj.ShouldNotBeNullOrEmpty();
Assert.IsType<string>(obj);
```

and both pass for `"[]"`

Comment: Is it JSON? Deserialise the value and check if the deserialised array is empty.

Comment: Well, the object isn't empty. The JSON array it represents is an empty array, but the object is `[]`, so it isn't empty.